# MySQL:Convert multiple varchar formats into DateTime

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I'm trying to convert varchar dates with multiple formats into a standard DateTime format so I can compare the dates between them. I wrote an SQL statement which I believe is on the right track but I know too little SQL to spot mistakes. My current code errors out. Here's what I have:

```
    DELIMITER //

    CREATE FUNCTION CUSTOM_DATE_CONVERT ( d VARCHAR(50) )
      RETURNS DATETIME

      BEGIN
        DECLARE date DATETIME;

        IF STR_TO_DATE

( d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s" ) IS NOT NULL THEN SET date = STR_TO_DATE( d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s" );
    ELSE
        IF STR_TO_DATE( d, "%H:%i:%s %b %d, %Y" ) IS NOT NULL THEN SET date = STR_TO_DATE( d, "%H:%i:%s %b %d, %Y" );
            END IF;
        RETURN date;
      END//

    DELIMITER ;

    SELECT id, CUSTOM_DATE_CONVERT( payment_date ) FROM `paypal_table`
```

And my error is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 12
```

Am I on the right track? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you set `DELIMITER` to something different from semicolon?

Comment: I didn't, thanks for catching that. I updated the code and error after setting the DELIMITER.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to the first if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you forget to include an `ENDIF`

```
IF STR_TO_DATE ... THEN SET date = STR_TO_DATE( d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s" );
ELSE
    IF ...THEN SET date = STR_TO_DATE( d, "%H:%i:%s %b %d, %Y" );
    END IF; /* close second if */
END IF;     /* close first if  */
```

see [example](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if-statement.html)